# Converting pygame file to exe with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

So i wanted to make an .exe file from a small game but when i try to build it, when i type:

```
setup.py build
```

it gives and error that pygame is not a module

```
C:\Python33\Projects>setup.py build
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Projects\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    executables = executables
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 362, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 232, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 619, in Freeze

    self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 378, in _GetMo
duleFinder
    finder.IncludePackage(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 686, in Include
Package
    module = self._ImportModule(name, deferredImports)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 386, in _Import
Module
    raise ImportError("No module named %r" % name)
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'

C:\Python33\Projects>
```

My setup file looks like this:

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("racegame.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Racegame",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages": ["pygame"],
                          "include_files": ["racecar.png"]}},
    description="A race game",

    executables = executables
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
setup(name="NAME OF YOUR PROGRAM",
         version="1.0",
         description="as above",
         executables=[Executable("NAME OF THE SCRIPT.py")])
```

Use this, I always executing with this.Copy-paste this codes to setup.py.And then you have to put that special files into your folder.Afer you executed it, drag your *png* files to folder into same folder with your program.

> So open the terminal (cmd) in the same directory with your program, write;

```
python setup.py build
```

Then put your png,jpg etc. files in to that folder. That's it.

> [**Here**](http://tinypic.com/r/oa4qkz/8) I record a video for you. In the folder that setup.py and your script stays,click *shift+right-click* and open the terminal in there. For example I drag the apple.png in video, so you must put the all special files where I put in video.
>
> **PLEASE BE SURE** your script starting with *#!/usr/bin/env python* . Otherwise Python can not find the Python directory and throws that error no module etc. **ALWAYS** start your scripts with that.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygame,random
import ChuckNorris

pygame.init()
#codes
```

Comment: which script do i need to add?